# Projection Pushdown Trino/Presto SQL (Athena)

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-athena, presto, trino

```
WITH data_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM table
)
SELECT id FROM data_table
```

Does Projection pushdown work in this case?

As you can see, In the CTE, I do a **SELECT** * from the table but then when I actually pull in the data, I pull in just the **column id**

In this case, does the query engine read and bring in all the columns from the table before filtering and displaying just the id column (which would be a big memory waste if there are multiple columns) or does the projection pushdown get applied and the query engine scans and fetches just the column id ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Trino will only select the columns that are relevant to computing the final results of the query.

You can see which columns are being read by running [`EXPLAIN`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html) on the query. For instance, given:

```
EXPLAIN WITH data_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM orders
)
SELECT orderkey FROM data_table
```

You can see that only the `orderkey` column is being read from the underlying table:

```
                                      Query Plan
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Trino version: 405
 Fragment 0 [tpch:orders:15000]
     Output layout: [orderkey]
     Output partitioning: SINGLE []
     Output[columnNames = [orderkey]]
     │   Layout: [orderkey:bigint]
     │   Estimates: {rows: 15000 (131.84kB), cpu: 0, memory: 0B, network: 0B}
     └─ TableScan[table = tpch:tiny:orders]
            Layout: [orderkey:bigint]    <<<<<<<<<<
            Estimates: {rows: 15000 (131.84kB), cpu: 131.84k, memory: 0B, network: 0B}
            orderkey := tpch:orderkey    <<<<<<<<<<
            tpch:orderstatus
                :: [[F], [O], [P]]
```